# ON/OFF Navigation Panel (Inter-Page Cache)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a small **sample page below** to show you what I mean.

Is there a was to keep the **.panelNav** Open when navigating to another page and Function just as an ON/OFF switch only when the user allows the change?

http://glustik.com/glustik2/page1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here are some suggestions:

- use AJAX to load another page directly into the content
  placeholder
- store a cookie value, and opening the menu when you get to another page if it is set.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the jQuery cookie plugin - https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie - and set the cookie to menuOpen or menuClose & write/rewrite it when the user changes the state of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, append a parameter (e.g. "?navopen=1") or a fragment identifier ("#navopen") to the linked URL and check for that in your $(document).ready function. This might be nicer than a cookie because it will follow the user's clicks around, but will not affect pages opened from other sources.